# C++ Inferring Template Arguments of Type Inside of Angle Brackets

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, generics, types

Is there anyway to simplify the type annotation in this line of code:

```
std::array<std::tuple<char, int>, 3> arr {{{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}}};
```

I thought this would work:

```
std::array<std::tuple> arr {{{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}}};
```

But it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array) to simplify to

```
auto arr = std::to_array({std::tuple{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}});
```

Comment: MSVC doesn't seem to like this, but not sure why: https://godbolt.org/z/exYTMPdMs

Answer (score 2):

A placeholder for a deduced class type, i.e. the name of a class template without a template argument list like `std::tuple`, cannot be used as a template argument.

CTAD (class template argument deduction) is only possible if the *whole* specified type is a placeholder for a deduced class type, e.g.

```
std::array{/*...*/}
```

where `std::array` is the placeholder naming a class template without template argument list. The template argument list must not be present *at all*. Even `std::array<int>{0, 1, 2, 3}` isn't possible.

The syntax you want isn't possible. You need to make some concessions like using `std::make_tuple` around each element of the array initializer.

Comment: Why does this not work: ```auto arr = std::array {{std::tuple {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}}};```

Comment: @vim_overlord That doesn't work because `std::array` is specified so that it requires each element of the initializer list to have a deducible type and all deduced types to be the same for the CTAD deduction guide to work. This is a design choice to avoid unintended implicit conversions. The other answer shows that `std::to_array` can be used instead because it doesn't have that restriction. I am still trying to figure out why MSVC rejects that though.